# Is it possible to only check the first four letters of a string during: input.equals("USER test"); JAVA POP3

Tags: java, pop3

I'm trying to make a mail system with POP3 commands using java.

When a user logs in, they enter "USER" followed by their username e.g "USER ben"

in order to send them along their way I was wondering if here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestingPart1 {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        int on = 1;
        while (on == 1){
        System.out.println("+OK POP3 server ready");

        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Input = answer.nextLine();

    **if (Input.equals.("USER test")){
        CommandInterpreter.handleUser(Input);
        }**
```

I would be able to only check the first four characters USER so that when it gets passed through to CommandInterpreter it still reads USER test, but passes this stage

thanks :)

Comment: `if (Input.startsWith("USER")) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Input.startsWith("USER ")) { ...
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much :) spent about an hour trying to problem solve, all I had to do was change a couple of letters :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a space into a string array. Then evaluate whether the first element of the array is equal to "USER"

Input is unchanged by the split operation.